MVN Depreciation warning for scipy.stats on the multivariate normal function MVNUN
Error:  DeprecationWarning: Please use mvnun from the scipy.stats namespace, the scipy.stats.mvn namespace is deprecated.
prob, _ = mvn.mvnun(lower_limit, upper_limit, mean, cov_matrix)
The line of code:
prob, _ = mvn.mvnun(lower_limit, upper_limit, mean, cov_matrix)
I am attempting to output a probability of a CDF using a covariance matrix, but I am worried that this function is being depreciated, anyone know the newest update to it?
